# Analysing relationships using autosomal DNA

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

I (A) am 1095 cm's from a known cousin (M).

I (A) am 1224 cm's from an unknown person (S)

My cousin (M) is 1458 cm's from the unknown person (S).

I (A) am described as a Cousin to (S)
(M) is described as a close relation to (S)

A is 73, M is 79 and S is 89.

What conclusion can be drawn?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Your question could be improved because as it is written it is not clear.  Please use standard terminology.  Don't make your readers guess what you really meant.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your starting point for this question should be to use [The Shared cM Project 3.0 tool v4](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4) which suggests these relationships for the shared cM value between each pair:

- A and M are 6 years apart in age and [share 1,095cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1095) suggesting that they are first cousins, assuming from their age difference that they belong to the same generation.  There is a tiny chance that they are half siblings.
- A and S are 16 years apart in age and [share 1,224cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1224) suggesting that they are first cousins, *if* they belong to the same generation.  There is a tiny chance that they are half siblings.  If they may be from different generations then it is possible that S is a half aunt or half uncle to A.
- M and S are 10 years apart in age and [share 1,458cM](http://%20-%20A%20and%20M%20are%206%20years%20apart%20in%20age%20and%20[share%201,095cM][2]%20suggesting%20that%20they%20are%20first%20cousins,%20assuming%20from%20their%20age%20difference%20that%20they%20belong%20to%20the%20same%20generation.%20%20There%20is%20a%20tiny%20chance%20that%20they%20are%20half%20siblings.) suggesting that they are half siblings, *if* they belong to the same generation.  There is a small chance that they are first cousins.  If they may be from different generations then it is possible that S is an aunt or uncle, or maybe a half aunt or half uncle to M.

If you know the relationship between A and M then you may be able to tighten up your hypothesis but my first one would be that M and S are half siblings, and A is a first cousin to both.

As [commented by @JanMurphy](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/15833/analysing-relationships-using-autosomal-dna#comment24916_15835) it is important to realize that

> we cannot determine relationships by the raw numbers alone. We must
>   use information from paper-trail research or knowledge of real-life
>   relationships

to flesh out and check any hypotheses we make from the raw numbers.